# How to fit some content correctly in a DIV?

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to show the content inside of a div, inside of the black box to be more precise,  but they are going one above the other.
I'm trying, but they keeping being one above the other, as you can see here : [www.rbsilva.com/store](http://www.rbsilva.com/store)
I would like to work like this : [www.rbsilva.com/works](http://www.rbsilva.com/works)

Any help ?

Comment: I dont see any problems. I think it looks great. You are going to have to be a little more specific.

Comment: Those two pages (besides copy) look identical to me.

Comment: they're identical yes, but I need to do some modifications, in works that's ok, but in store I need to be able to increase the black box, which says about the info, this dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

which black box are you talking about?

if you're talking about getting the text over the image you could apply the following css:

```
.portfolio-image-holder{
    position:relative;
}
.portfolio-info{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-250px;
}
```